# How to put an image on two columns in a conference document class

Tags: floats, columns, ieeeconf

i know this question has been asked and solved a lot of times, tried to use figure*, \onecolumn...

there is my code

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=12cm,height=8cm]{prop.png}
    \caption{Propriétés Structurelles des Graphes}
\end{figure}
```

if i put figure* the image goes at the top of the next page, if i use \onecolumn and \twocolumns it creates a new page with only my image. I tried also to put the image on non-floating but nothing works.

there is my use packages :

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines=true}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
```

Comment: use figure* and just move it forwards in the source so it comes on the page you want

Comment: please don't use answer postings for comments. Do you really want a figure above the title on the first page? are you sure that would be accepted by whichever journal is using this class?